# Create trigger to insert primary key from one table upon creation of new row, into column of another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables I'm working with: Records and Invoice. Invoice contains a column for the primary key of Records to be stored as a foreign key.

I'm looking to create a trigger. Immediately when a new row is generated in Records, I want a new row to also be created in Invoice, and I want the PK from Records to be inserted into the corresponding column in invoice.

For example, let's say the tables are Records(RecordsID) and invoice(invoiceID, RecordsID)

```
When new row created in tbl Records     
Create new row in tbl Invoice and insert new Records.RecordID into new invoice.invoiceID
```

I'm aware this is most likely very far off, but here is the trigger I've been working on:

```
DELIMITER $$

create trigger new_invoice
after insert
on main for each row
begin
if new.RecordID is not null then
insert into invoice(RecordID)
values(new.RecordID(new.RecordID));
END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Is Records.RecordsID an auto_increment column?

Comment: It is auto increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have it almost right

> ```
> CREATE tABLE main(RecordID int)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE invoice (RecordID int)
> ```

> ```
> create trigger new_invoice
> after insert
> on main for each row
> begin
> if new.RecordID is not null then
> insert into invoice(RecordID)
> values(new.RecordID);
> END IF;
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO main VALUES (1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM invoice
> ```
>
> ```
> | RecordID |
> | -------: |
> |        1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=594b81a243990178232b66ddd3d4d7e1)*

Comment: Unfortunately I seem to get a syntax error when I attempt to run this. Here's the error: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MqirNpf5ChUJwmJJykqz7nsDGwnof_jD?usp=sharing

Comment: You probably need to set delimiters